#ifndef __HEADER_H__ #define __HEADER_H__ in CAPL
What I'm trying is to separate function definitions from main .can file.
The problem is, when including same .cin file in different .can files, the multiple definition compile error occurs.
I've tried #pragma once, and #ifndef __HEADER_CIN__, #define __HEADER_CIN__, since it looks quite similar to C/C++.
Below is the codes I've tried.

"header.cin" :
#ifndef __HEADER_CIN__
#define __HEADER_CIN__

includes
{
    // ...
}

variables
{
    // ...
}

on start
{
    // ...
}

#endif


Is there any way to solve this problem?

Header guards won't save you from multiple definitions in C or C++ either, in case the header is included in multiple different translation units. The correct solution in C or C++ is to avoid object/function definitions in header files.

CAPL is not C or C++ and a .cin file is not a header file. A .cin include file should be used more or less like a .can file except it is reusable. I would advise to only define variables and functions in a .cin file (that is, avoid event handlers in .cin files). Can you give code examples of the problem you are trying to solve with the include guard?

CAPL won't support using those #defines. Instead you can use dll using pragma
